# Send SOAP requests on multiple threads

Tags: testing, groovy, performance-testing, soapui

I use SoapUI with Groovy script to send SOAP reuquests in multiple threads. There is a list of IDs in a txt file, and have to put these one by one in SOAP request and send it. I try to execute this on multiple threads.
I wrote following script, but it performs too slowly. It seems, there aren't 40 threads simultaneously.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*

def threadPoolSize = 40
def executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize)
def completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(executorService)

def props = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties");
def testStepSend = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Send request")

def dt = String.format('__%tF_%<tH_%<tM', java.time.LocalDateTime.now())
def resultFile = new File("C:\\testing\\" + "myResult_" + dt + ".txt")
resultFile.createNewFile() 

props.setPropertyValue("resultFile", resultFile.toString());

def is = new File("C:\\testing\\mylist.txt").newInputStream()

is.eachLine { line ->
    def future = completionService.submit({
        if(line.toString().length() > 0){
            props.setPropertyValue("uuid", line.toString());
            testStepSend.run(testRunner, context)
        }
        return null
    } as Callable<Void>)
    
    future.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
}

executorService.shutdown()
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)

is.close()

def dontCare = null;
```